# FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: 'Mailing Country' contains an invalid country name

Tags: error

I am getting an error "'Mailing Country' contains an invalid country name" when I am trying to update contact email address.I don't see any validation rules or triggers on Mailing country field.I have **blanks**  in most of the contacts Mailing country field.

Comment: Do you have state and country picklist enabled?

Comment: yes it is enabled

Comment: You need to set the value to one of the countries listed in the picklist.

Comment: if importing from s/s or api - the value needs to match the Integration Value as defined in the Manage State and Country Picklists Setup. Integration Value may not be the same as the user-displayed value in the UI